# three.js - get X,Y,Z rotation values from Matrix4

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js is there a way to tell/compute/get specific rotation values (X/Y/Z) from the Matrix4 in degrees (float), please?

As unfortunately among many of its functions there is no such directly implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this question was actually "simple" (at least for an experienced three.js user out there as I was told by such user elsewhere): use three.js `Euler` class `.setFromRotationMatrix()` function and use correct order (in my case I first wrongly thought it is simply XYZ while it actually was YZX - beware with this, you have to get this part right!) - and yea, that's it!

Comment: with .setFromRotationMatrix() you can set rotation to an object. but how to return x y z rotation values sperately?

Answer (score -2):

I *think* your question is "Q: How do I convert radians to degrees?"

- `var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;`
- `var degrees = radians * 180.0 / Math.PI;`

Comment: no, it is not: my question is how you get, for example, rotation X value as float (or radians - it does not matter in which of those two as later I would convert that float to radians anyway) from a Matrix4 looking like this:
0.66799456, -0.33590272, 0.6640426, 52.21598, 0.0, 0.8923312, 0.45138136, 39.204815, -0.74416614, -0.3015203, 0.5960723, 47.337257, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0

Comment: And what exactly do you need that [.extractRotation()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.extractRotation) doesn't already do?  X/Y/Z are in radians, of course - but you can easily convert to degrees.  But it gives you "specific rotation values (X/Y/Z) from the Matrix4".  You can initialize your destination matrix to "0".  You can disregard Y and Z if you want.

Comment: I explained it here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/get-x-y-z-rotation-values-from-matrix4 (basically I am not using three.js, I am in JAVA, but in there there is kind of port of that three.js Matrix4 class) - I need that rotation info (value) to rotate object by rotation values from matrix of another object

Comment: 1) It's spelled "Java", not "JAVA".  2) Your question stated "In three.js is there a way to tell/compute/get specific rotation values (X/Y/Z)?"; I gave you one answer.  Another answer would be "simply read those entries you want directly from the matrix".  3) It's just a "Transformation matrix".  Look here for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Comment: 1.) what change it make if I write it JAVA or Java?! Absurd..you are looking for problems where arre none. 2.) yes: in my JAVA code there is a Matrix4 probable port of the same class as in three.js but beccause the src I use in my JAVA app has been discontinued like 10+ yers ago and as it is basically the same I am asking it under three.js - I see nothing strange about it (if you would read the link I gave you would already know, nevermind) 3.) all those info links you gave tell me nothing practical - I am not that good therefore I am asking here hoping for some code example I could test

Comment: Anyway, I just solved it by porting three.js Euler class function `.getRotationFromMatrix()` to JAVA and setting the order to YXZ - now I can get those rotaiton values easily exactly as expected!